# How to send escape sequences via UART, using Embedded C code

Tags: c, escaping, uart, unicode-escapes, stringescapeutils

I need help in sending a specific escape sequence, using Embedded C.
This is my very first topic at stackoverflow!

I use this function to write commands through UART:

```
void UART_Write(UARTChannel* channel, uint8_t* data, uint32_t length)
```

The inputs, channel, data and length, correspond with the UART channel, the command to be send and the length of the command, respectively.
This works great in general!

However, I have some difficulties in generating the correct escape sequence in C. I need to write the following escape sequence, using the UART_Write function:

```
EscR0,1,2,7;
```

`Esc` being the Escape character (0x1b), `R0` being the character command designator, `1,2,7` being the context specific parameters and `;` being the termination sign.

How can I make the input "data" to the function "UART_Write" be equal to the escape sequence EscR0,1,2,7; in Embedded C?

I suppose it can be done in many different ways, but any suggestions will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you want to send 'esc' or do you want to send '1b' as a hex value?

just send the characters, just like you would any other character string

for instance for the example: `EscR0,1,2,7;`:

```
char buffer[20] = {'\0'};
buffer[0] = 0x1b;
strcat( buffer, "R0,1,2,6;" );
....
```